# Smoothen Heatmap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
X = c(6,6.2,6.4,6.6,6.8,5.6,5.8,6,6.2,6.4,6.6,6.8,7,7.2,7.4,7.6,7.8,8,2.8,3,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5)
Y = c(2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.8)
Value = c(0,0.00683254,0,0.007595654,0.015517884,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.005219395,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.002892342,0,0.002758141,0)
table = data.frame(X, Y, Value)
```

I have put together a heatmap in R, based on the following command:

```
  ggplot(data = table, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = Value), colour = 'black') + 
    theme_void() + 
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "black") + xlab(label = "X") + ylab(label = "Y")
```

Since there is not a value for every X and Y, it leads to plots that appear as follows.

[image]

I am attempting to smoothen the plot and have the following question:

As there are small white spaces between the plotted values, how could one color these white spaces to be the median intensity? Said differently, how would I first create an initial layer with non-zero median 'Value' before plotting the non-zero 'Value' on top (overlayed)?

A sample is shown below, which has been 'smoothed', which looks closer to the desired output.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) Right now, it is hard to answer all of your questions without testing it. Can you clarify your question 2 ? Can you show a drawing of the expected output ?

Comment: Good points dc37. I have tried to clarify the post to address your questions.

Comment: @user2657817 A (mock-up) drawing of your expected output would help a lot. I'm not sure what you're looking for. You mention the terms "smoothen" and "interpolate"; it's not clear to me what you want to smoothen/interpolate. Smoothen how? Interpolate what based on what?

Comment: Clarified the questions and added a mockup

Comment: another possible approach is to use geom_rect() and set all four corners such that the complete heat map is filled.  but as others have said its not completely clear what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will totally fit your need but from my understanding you have some missing values and combination of X and Y.

So, you can use `complete` function from `tidyr` to get all different combinations of X and Y (those without values will be filled with `NA`) and then by using `na.value` argument in `scale_fill_gradient2` function, you can set the values of these `NA` values to the same color of the midpoint value:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
table %>% complete(X,Y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y))+
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Value), interpolate = TRUE)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", mid = "grey",high = "black",
                       na.value = "grey")
```

[image]
Does it answer your question ?